# Vector and polynoms - two little but hard tasks from an exam

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm writing linear algebra exam in some months and I have looked for some old exams on the internet but unfortunately they are without solutions. I could solve some but this kind, I don't know at all how to do it:

Let $\mathbb{R}[x]$ be the R-vector space of all polynoms in the variable $x$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathbb{R}_{n}[x]$ be the set of real polynoms $p$ of the order $n_{p} \leq n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$.

1.Let $p,q \in \mathbb{R}_{n}[x]$ be two polynoms. Which condition is necessary so that we have $p+q \in \mathbb{R}_{m}[x]$ for an $m \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ with $m < n$?

2.How much you need to set $m \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ at least, so that for all $p,q \in \mathbb{R}_{n}[x]$ the subspace $\mathbb{R}_{m}[x]$ includes the polynom $p \cdot q$ ?

I hope you can help me because so far we didn't have these kind of tasks and I'm very scared if we get such complicated text task in the exam too : /

Maybe if I'm lucky it will be similar to this one but not sure how this could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hardly about linear algebra, but just about polynomials. For 1. the obvious reply would be "the condition $\deg(p+q)\neq n$", but maybe this is considered a bit *too* obvious. You could say "the coefficients of $X^n$ in $p$ and $q$ are opposite (so they cancel in $p+q$)" instead. And question 2. appears to be about the well known relation $\deg(pq)=\deg p+\deg q$. (By the way $\deg$ stands for "degree", what you called "order".)

Comment: Merci beaucoup! :)